# SonarQube issue" Add at least one assertion to this test case" for junit and Mockito

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube, mockito, assertions

I'm having issues with SonarQube raising issues with several of my unit tests, prompting the following issue:

```
@InjectMocks
private MessageEscaper escaper;
@Mock
private SLogger mockLogger;

@Mock
private Messagetext mocktext;

 @Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    escaper = new MessageEscaper ();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

}


 @Test
public void Message() {

    assertTrue(escaper.handleText(mockText));
    verify(mockLogger).logMessage(mockText);
    assertEquals(true, escaper.handleText(mockText));

}
```

The escaper.handleText(mockText) returns a Boolean. Even if i have assert statements i still get an issue " Add at least one assertion to this test case". Though both the assert statements are similar i felt sonar might pick at least one of them.

this is the method that gets the actual call.

```
public boolean handleText(MessageText text)
{                                
  try {
     Message message = context.getMessage();
     String serviceName = Util.getServiceName(message);
     text.put(MESSAGE_OPERATION, serviceName);
  } catch (CustomException | RuntimeException e) {
     if (LOG.isLoggable(Level.ERROR)) {
        LOG.warning("Unable to store : " + UtilLog.print(e));
     }
  }
  return true;
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the plugin version.Worked for me

Comment: worth precising updating from which version to which version.

Comment: In my case it was from "2.2" to "2.5"

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, I was able solve it with the following code...

```
@Test(expected = Test.None.class /* no exception expected */)
```

rather than

```
@Test()
```